# Las data record format reading

Tags: python, lidar

I have a LAS file and I need to gather the values from each attribute from it. I already know the data types:

> X_Easting, Y_Northing, Z_Elevation, Intensity, ReturnNum, NumOfReturns, ScanDirFlag, EdgeFlightLine, Classification, ScanAngleRank, UserData, PointSourceID, GPS_TIME, Red, Green, Blue

Similar to [this](http://www.lidar.com.tw/docs/asprs_las_spec_v13.pdf) on the 11th page bottom one.

I can access a few of those with the following:

```
import laspy
inFile = laspy.file.File("lasfile.las", mode="r")
print inFile.x
print inFile.y
print inFile.z
print inFile.intensity
print inFile.red
print inFile.green
print inFile.blue
```

I need the others as well, but I don't know how to call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to find out something like this is to take a look at the object you want to know more about in an interactive python shell:

```
me@machine:~$ python
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:50:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import laspy
>>> las_file = laspy.file.File("lasfile.las", mode='r')
>>> help(las_file)
```

This shows you the documentation for the `File` class provided by laspy. There you can find a list of all attributes that you are looking for.

**Edit:** I saw in another post of yours that you are developing on windows. To get to the interpreter execute python.exe from your start menu. If you are using IDLE you can also use its built in shell.

---

If you ever face a not so well documented package you can also use:

```
>>> dir(las_file)
['Blue', 'Classification', 'Green', 'Intensity', ...]
```

This shows you all entries in the dictionary of the object you want to look at (in this case `las_file`). This gives you all methods and attributes in a list without any explanation, so it might be a bit convoluted, but it works fine if you just want to take a quick glance at what is there to work with.

I hope this helps. And thank you for making me aware that a package like this exists :)

Comment: I could find everything with the "help(las_file)" command. The --More-- was a bit tricky for me but now everything is good. I tried the "dir(las_file)" too but it didn't do anything. Did I miss something?

Comment: The `dir` function should work if you execute it after the code I posted above. If that does not work you can try `d = dir(las_file)` and `print d` and see what happens. It should also work on any other object, like, for example: `dir(int)`. You can find a more comprehensive explanation of `dir` and other built-in functions [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)